# Clone repository into GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have been using git locally for while a now and have a private repository with complete change history etc. I now want to share this on GitHub, so I need to clone from my local repo into a new GitHub repo. I cannot find any way to do this. How can I get all my history up onto GitHub?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't need to "clone onto GitHub". You just have to create a repository on GitHub and push your changes there:

```
$ cd your_local_repo
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks - and that will keep my commit history?

Comment: Yes, everything from your local repo's master branch will be pushed to GitHub one. If you got some tags, you would also want to push them via `git push --tags`.

Comment: I would add that for the first push, `--mirror` with `-u` might be a sensible thing to use: `git push --mirror -u origin`

Comment: "Official" article on the subject: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Comment: It's my understanding that `clone` copies all the branches in a repository, not just the `master` branch. If that's true, then it seems like following the instructions in the answer will have a different effect than running `clone` from the remote location. Is there a way to modify the instructions so they have more nearly the same effect as running `clone` from the remote location?

Answer (score 6):

You simply want to create a new repository on your account on GitHub. Assuming your account name is `CraigH`, and you call you new repository `NewRepo` (imaginative, I know), you'd simply (assuming you have GitHub keys set up on your system properly):

1. Add a remote to your local repository

   - `git remote add origin git@github.com:CraigH/NewRepo.git`
2. Push out your current history to GitHub

   - `git push --set-upstream origin master`

And from that point, your history in the `master` branch are in GitHub's `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can "reverse clone" your local repo (or remote, it doesn't matter) "old_repo" into a new, already created, github repo "new_repo", with all its branches and tags, like this:

- First, create a local "bare clone" of your old_repo in an empty folder:

  - cd to this folder
  - git clone --bare "old_repo"
- Now push it to your new_repo in mirror mode:

  - cd old_repo.git
  - git push --mirror https://github.com/your_user/new_repo.git
- You can now delete the local folder with the bare clone if you want.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

You do this by pushing to remote repo on GitHub. You should get the whole history and everything.